How to control number of concurrent jdbc connections made by spark, while executing a read query?
I have a list of items to be fetched from a table (let's say items) in my db. My database has many clusters and every item may belong to a different cluster.(I already know to which cluster an item belongs).
I want to fetch all the data in the items table for all the items in my list. This data can be huge so I am using Spark to fetch the data.
Now, there is a limit of 15 concurrent connections per cluster that I can make. Also I want limited number of items to be fetched in a single query (so that long running queries can be avoided).
How can I acheive this in spark ?
I am able to limit the number of items to be fetched in a single query by dividing the items into multiple predicates, each containing 10 items. But I am unable to limit the concurrent connections to 15.
I have tried the following code
sparkSession.read
.option("driver", drivername)
.option("numPartitions", 15)
.jdbc(s"$jdbcUrl", select_query, predicates, connectionProperties) 

